# IOS Build Issue Photon Unity

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

while build ios project i receive this issues,
I am making a unity project that works with photon,i dont understand why i am getting this.Can you help me about this?

> Ld
>   /Users/efekanpulatli/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-dyjednsrlolpqpfrhyygomenxswt/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/onur.app/onur
>   normal arm64
>       cd /Users/efekanpulatli/fps2/fps2/FPSOnur
>       export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.0
>       export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++
>   -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.2.sdk
>   -L/Users/efekanpulatli/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-dyjednsrlolpqpfrhyygomenxswt/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos
>   -L/Users/efekanpulatli/fps2/fps2/FPSOnur -L/Users/efekanpulatli/fps2/fps2/FPSOnur/Libraries -F/Users/efekanpulatli/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-dyjednsrlolpqpfrhyygomenxswt/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos
>   -F/Users/efekanpulatli/fps2/fps2/FPSOnur/Pods/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/Frameworks/frameworks
>   -F/Users/efekanpulatli/fps2/fps2/FPSOnur/Frameworks/Plugins/iOS -F/Users/efekanpulatli/fps2/fps2/FPSOnur/Frameworks/Plugins/iOS/GoogleMobileAdsSdkiOS-7.15.0
>   -filelist /Users/efekanpulatli/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-dyjednsrlolpqpfrhyygomenxswt/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Unity-iPhone.build/Debug-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/arm64/onur.LinkFileList
>   -Xlinker -map -Xlinker /Users/efekanpulatli/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-dyjednsrlolpqpfrhyygomenxswt/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Unity-iPhone.build/Debug-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/onur-LinkMap-normal-arm64.txt
>   -miphoneos-version-min=7.0 -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/efekanpulatli/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-dyjednsrlolpqpfrhyygomenxswt/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Unity-iPhone.build/Debug-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/arm64/onur_lto.o
>   -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -stdlib=libc++ -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -ObjC -framework AVFoundation -framework AudioToolbox -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreMedia -framework CoreMotion -framework
>   CoreTelephony -framework CoreVideo -framework GLKit -framework
>   GoogleMobileAds -framework MediaPlayer -framework MessageUI -framework
>   MobileCoreServices -framework OpenGLES -framework Security -framework
>   StoreKit -framework SystemConfiguration -weak_framework AdSupport
>   -weak_framework JavaScriptCore -weak_framework SafariServices -weak_framework WebKit -weak_framework CoreMotion -weak-lSystem -framework MediaToolbox -liPhone-lib -framework CoreText -framework AudioToolbox -weak_framework AVFoundation -framework CFNetwork
>   -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreMedia -weak_framework CoreMotion -framework CoreVideo -framework Foundation -framework MediaPlayer -framework OpenAL -framework OpenGLES -framework QuartzCore -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -liconv.2 -framework UnityAds -framework GoogleMobileAds -framework StoreKit -framework GameKit -weak_framework GameController
>   -weak_framework Metal -lPods-Unity-iPhone -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/efekanpulatli/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-dyjednsrlolpqpfrhyygomenxswt/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Unity-iPhone.build/Debug-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/arm64/onur_dependency_info.dat
>   -o /Users/efekanpulatli/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-dyjednsrlolpqpfrhyygomenxswt/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/onur.app/onur
>
> ld: warning: arm64 function not 4-byte aligned: ltmp0 from
>   /Users/efekanpulatli/fps2/fps2/FPSOnur/Libraries/libiPhone-lib.a(unwind_test_arm64.o)
>   ld: warning: arm64 function not 4-byte aligned: _unwind_tester from
>   /Users/efekanpulatli/fps2/fps2/FPSOnur/Libraries/libiPhone-lib.a(unwind_test_arm64.o)
>   Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:   "_opus_strerror",
>   referenced from:
>         _Wrapper_opus_strerror_m1319147986 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_2.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Wrapper_opus_strerror_m1319147986)   "_opus_decode", referenced from:
>         _Wrapper_opus_decode_m2633376548 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_2.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Wrapper_opus_decoder_create_m58742900, _Wrapper_opus_decode_m2633376548 , _Wrapper_opus_decode_m681748887_MetadataUsageId , _Wrapper_get_opus_decoder_ctl_m172931426 , _Wrapper_opus_decoder_create_m58742900_MetadataUsageId , _Wrapper_opus_decoder_ctl_get_m3867966095 , _Wrapper_set_opus_decoder_ctl_m2527606227_MetadataUsageId , _Wrapper_set_opus_decoder_ctl_m2527606227 , _Wrapper_opus_decoder_destroy_m2431554144 , _Wrapper_get_opus_decoder_ctl_m172931426_MetadataUsageId , _Wrapper_opus_decoder_init_m2606826805 , _Wrapper_opus_decoder_destroy_m2431554144_MetadataUsageId , _Wrapper_opus_decoder_ctl_set_m4146398121 , _Wrapper_opus_decode_m681748887 , _Wrapper_opus_decode_m2794170649_MetadataUsageId , _Wrapper_opus_decode_m2794170649 , _Wrapper_opus_decoder_get_size_m885163317 , _Wrapper_opus_decode_float_m49627027 )   "_opus_decoder_init", referenced from:
>         _Wrapper_opus_decoder_init_m2606826805 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_2.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Wrapper_opus_decoder_init_m2606826805)   "_opus_decoder_ctl_get", referenced from:
>         _Wrapper_opus_decoder_ctl_get_m3867966095 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_2.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Wrapper_opus_decoder_ctl_get_m3867966095)   "_opus_decoder_ctl_set", referenced from:
>         _Wrapper_opus_decoder_ctl_set_m4146398121 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_2.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Wrapper_opus_decoder_ctl_set_m4146398121)   "_opus_encoder_ctl_get", referenced from:
>         _Wrapper_opus_encoder_ctl_get_m1103128133 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_2.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Wrapper_opus_encoder_ctl_get_m1103128133)   "_opus_decode_float", referenced from:
>         _Wrapper_opus_decode_float_m49627027 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_2.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Wrapper_opus_decode_float_m49627027)   "_opus_encode", referenced from:
>         _Wrapper_opus_encode_m52685205 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_2.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Wrapper_opus_encoder_ctl_set_m1615502419, _Wrapper_get_opus_encoder_ctl_m2810746622_MetadataUsageId , _Wrapper_set_opus_encoder_ctl_m3840159733_MetadataUsageId , _Wrapper_get_opus_encoder_ctl_m2810746622 , _Wrapper_set_opus_encoder_ctl_m3840159733 , _Wrapper_opus_encode_m3033062402 , _Wrapper_opus_encode_m3033062402_MetadataUsageId , _Wrapper_opus_encoder_destroy_m625817532 , _Wrapper_opus_encoder_init_m15560055 , _Wrapper_opus_encode_m52685205 , _Wrapper_opus_encode_m577238578_MetadataUsageId ,
>   _Wrapper_opus_encode_float_m3301075186 , _Wrapper_opus_encoder_destroy_m625817532_MetadataUsageId , _Wrapper_opus_encode_m577238578 , _Wrapper_opus_encoder_create_m1464755408 , _Wrapper_opus_encoder_ctl_get_m1103128133 , _Wrapper_opus_encoder_get_size_m1258208747 , _Wrapper_opus_encoder_create_m1464755408_MetadataUsageId )   "_opus_encoder_get_size", referenced from:
>         _Wrapper_opus_encoder_get_size_m1258208747 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_2.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Wrapper_opus_encoder_get_size_m1258208747)   "_opus_get_version_string", referenced from:
>         _Wrapper_opus_get_version_string_m1473983917 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_2.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Wrapper_opus_get_version_string_m1473983917)   "_speex_echo_ctl", referenced from:
>         _SpeexLib_speex_echo_ctl_m2144782039 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_2.o
>        (maybe you meant: _SpeexLib_speex_echo_ctl_m2144782039, _SpeexLib_speex_echo_ctl_m248029188 , _SpeexLib_speex_echo_ctl_m248029188_MetadataUsageId , _SpeexLib_speex_echo_ctl_m3504501606_MetadataUsageId , _SpeexLib_speex_echo_ctl_m3504501606 )   "_Photon_Audio_In_Read", referenced from:
>         _AppleAudioInReader_Photon_Audio_In_Read_m1290705999 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>        (maybe you meant: _AppleAudioInReader_Photon_Audio_In_Read_m1290705999)   "_speex_echo_cancellation", referenced from:
>         _SpeexLib_speex_echo_cancellation_m1881620855 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_2.o
>        (maybe you meant: _SpeexLib_speex_echo_cancellation_m1881620855)   "_speex_echo_playback", referenced from:
>         _SpeexLib_speex_echo_playback_m3129406855 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_2.o
>        (maybe you meant: _SpeexLib_speex_echo_playback_m3129406855)   "_speex_echo_capture", referenced from:
>         _SpeexLib_speex_echo_capture_m3263997405 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_2.o
>        (maybe you meant: _SpeexLib_speex_echo_capture_m3263997405)   "_speex_echo_state_reset", referenced from:
>         _SpeexLib_speex_echo_state_reset_m1584187788 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_2.o
>        (maybe you meant: _SpeexLib_speex_echo_state_reset_m1584187788)   "_speex_preprocess_state_init", referenced from:
>         _SpeexLib_speex_preprocess_state_init_m920390757 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_2.o
>        (maybe you meant: _SpeexLib_speex_preprocess_state_init_m920390757)   "_speex_preprocess_ctl", referenced from:
>         _SpeexLib_speex_preprocess_ctl_m2760114498 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_2.o
>        (maybe you meant: _SpeexLib_speex_preprocess_ctl_m1692717383, _SpeexLib_speex_preprocess_ctl_m2019210907 , _SpeexLib_speex_preprocess_ctl_m2760114498 , _SpeexLib_speex_preprocess_ctl_m2019210907_MetadataUsageId , _SpeexLib_speex_preprocess_ctl_m1692717383_MetadataUsageId )   "_opus_encode_float", referenced from:
>         _Wrapper_opus_encode_float_m3301075186 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_2.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Wrapper_opus_encode_float_m3301075186)   "_speex_echo_state_init_mc", referenced from:
>         _SpeexLib_speex_echo_state_init_mc_m1211960441 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_2.o
>        (maybe you meant: _SpeexLib_speex_echo_state_init_mc_m1211960441)   "_speex_echo_state_init", referenced from:
>         _SpeexLib_speex_echo_state_init_m1241577016 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_2.o
>        (maybe you meant: _SpeexLib_speex_echo_state_init_m1241577016, _SpeexLib_speex_echo_state_init_mc_m1211960441 )   "_opus_decoder_get_size", referenced from:
>         _Wrapper_opus_decoder_get_size_m885163317 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_2.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Wrapper_opus_decoder_get_size_m885163317)   "_opus_encoder_init", referenced from:
>         _Wrapper_opus_encoder_init_m15560055 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_2.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Wrapper_opus_encoder_init_m15560055)   "_opus_packet_get_bandwidth", referenced from:
>         _Wrapper_opus_packet_get_bandwidth_m3613265897 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_2.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Wrapper_opus_packet_get_bandwidth_m3613265897)   "_Photon_Audio_In_Destroy", referenced from:
>         _AppleAudioInPusher_Photon_Audio_In_Destroy_m32654017 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>         _AppleAudioInReader_Photon_Audio_In_Destroy_m3601082749 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>        (maybe you meant: _AppleAudioInReader_Photon_Audio_In_Destroy_m3601082749, _AppleAudioInPusher_Photon_Audio_In_Destroy_m32654017 )   "_opus_encoder_ctl_set", referenced from:
>         _Wrapper_opus_encoder_ctl_set_m1615502419 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_2.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Wrapper_opus_encoder_ctl_set_m1615502419)   "_Photon_IOSAudio_ForceToSpeaker", referenced from:
>         _IOSAudioForceToSpeaker_Photon_IOSAudio_ForceToSpeaker_m2568291807 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_2.o
>        (maybe you meant: _IOSAudioForceToSpeaker_Photon_IOSAudio_ForceToSpeaker_m2568291807)   "_speex_preprocess_run", referenced from:
>         _SpeexLib_speex_preprocess_run_m3765147464 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_2.o
>        (maybe you meant: _SpeexLib_speex_preprocess_run_m3765147464)   "_speex_echo_state_destroy", referenced from:
>         _SpeexLib_speex_echo_state_destroy_m1065560147 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_2.o
>        (maybe you meant: _SpeexLib_speex_echo_state_destroy_m1065560147)   "_speex_preprocess_state_destroy", referenced from:
>         _SpeexLib_speex_preprocess_state_destroy_m3308566994 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_2.o
>        (maybe you meant: _SpeexLib_speex_preprocess_state_destroy_m3308566994)   "_opus_packet_get_nb_channels", referenced from:
>         _Wrapper_opus_packet_get_nb_channels_m3496370129 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_2.o
>        (maybe you meant: _Wrapper_opus_packet_get_nb_channels_m3496370129)   "_Photon_Audio_In_CreatePusher", referenced from:
>         _AppleAudioInPusher_Photon_Audio_In_CreatePusher_m1174468635 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>        (maybe you meant: _AppleAudioInPusher_Photon_Audio_In_CreatePusher_m1174468635)   "_Photon_Audio_In_CreateReader", referenced from:
>         _AppleAudioInReader_Photon_Audio_In_CreateReader_m2771100524 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_0.o
>        (maybe you meant: _AppleAudioInReader_Photon_Audio_In_CreateReader_m2771100524) ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64 clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added a reference to the Opus Library? It looks like its failing to compile because the library is missing or the version of your library isnt arm64 compatible

Comment: you saved my day!I just reimport Photon Voice Library and fixed!

Comment: Glad I could help :-)